# Problems with scraping Bing translations

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I was "blessed" with a problem, and after some days of research I came here to ask for some help. I have a code that, legend says, used to work. It scrapes outputs from Bing Translator.
Now people can't get it to work. I never had any contact with Web Scraping and Python before, and tho I've spent the last 5 days learning about Web Scraping with Python, I still couldn't identify the problem.

Well, there were some updates on the website. I've tried updating it on header posts, etc. But it's still not working, and returning the same error.

```
import re
import json
import os
import argparse
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter
import getpass
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit


def bing_translator(text, from_, to_, proxy, user, sp):
    url = 'https://www.bing.com/ttranslate?&category=&IG=27062B7B735B438C891A574ACC3E57DE&IID=translator.5034.1'

    if type(user) != type(None):
        user_auth = user
        if type(sp) != type(None):
            user_auth = user_auth + ":" + sp
    #user_auth = "fg824gk:Abc.123456"

    if type(proxy) != type(None):
        if type(user) != type(None):
            proxy_Dict = {"http":"http://"+user_auth+"@"+proxy+":8080","https":"http://"+user_auth+"@"+proxy+":8443"}
        else:
            proxy_Dict = {"http":"http://"+proxy+":8080","https":"http://"+proxy+":8443"}

    post_header = {}

    post_header['Host'] = 'www.bing.com'
    post_header['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
    post_header['Accept'] = '*/*'
    post_header['Accept-Language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
    post_header['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate'
    post_header['Referer'] = 'https://www.bing.com/'
    post_header['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    post_header['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'

    data_payload = {'text' : text, 'from' : from_, 'to' : to_}

    parameters_payload = {'IG' : '839D27F8277F4AA3B0EDB83C255D0D70', 'IID' : 'translator.5033.3'}

    if type(proxy) != type(None):
        page = requests.post(url, headers = post_header, data=data_payload, proxies = proxy_Dict) #, params = payload_paramters)
    else:
        page = requests.post(url, headers = post_header, data=data_payload)

    try:
        j = json.loads(page.content[page.content.find('{'.encode("utf8")):page.content.find('}'.encode("utf8"))+1])
    except ValueError:
        print ('\n\n')
        print (data_payload)
        print ('\n\n')
        print ('\n\n')
        print (len(page.content))
        print (page.content)
        for i in page.content:
            print (ord(i))
        print ('\n\n')
        print ('\n\n')
        sys.exit(1)

    return j
```

When I run `bing("Platypus","en","es",None,None,None)`, the expected output would be "Ornitorrinco", but I get that error:

```
{'text': 'Platypus', 'from': 'en', 'to': 'es'}






88955

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NikolasP/Desktop/adsdsadsaadsadsa.py", line 48, in bing_translator
    j = json.loads(page.content[page.content.find('{'.encode("utf8")):page.content.find('}'.encode("utf8"))+1])
  File "C:\Users\NikolasP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\NikolasP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\NikolasP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    bing_translator("Platypus","en","es",None,None,None)
  File "C:/Users/NikolasP/Desktop/adsdsadsaadsadsa.py", line 57, in bing_translator
    print (ord(i))
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Comment: There error says "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)" and the code says `data_payload = {'text' : text, 'from' : from_, 'to' : to_}`. Did you try changing that to `data_payload = {"text" : text, "from" : from_, "to" : to_}`? Also, I don't think is really MVCE. You should be able to isolate the error much more (e.g. you've tagged this web-scraping, but the error doesn't seem to be caused by the scraping itself, but rather with what you're doing with the scraped data.)

Comment: to debug, first of all print the raw response you get, before any manipulations, so that you (and we) know what you dealing with

Comment: bing has a free tier for their translate API (<2M characters per month). this would probably be easier than scraping https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the url (inspect the request posted in browser). just add `v3` after `ttranslate`

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.bing.com/ttranslatev3'

post_header = {}
post_header['Host'] = 'www.bing.com'
post_header['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
post_header['Accept'] = '*/*'
post_header['Accept-Language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
post_header['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate'
post_header['Referer'] = 'https://www.bing.com/'
post_header['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
post_header['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'

parameters_payload = {'IG' : '839D27F8277F4AA3B0EDB83C255D0D70', 'IID' : 'translator.5033.3'}
data_payload = {'text':'Platypus', 'from':'en', 'to':'es'}
resp = requests.post(url, headers=post_header, params=parameters_payload, data=data_payload)

print(resp.json())
```

output

```
[{'detectedLanguage': {'language': 'en', 'score': 1.0}, 'translations': [{'text': 'Ornitorrinco', 'to': 'es'}]}]
```